# Texture mapping problem on a cone

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]I have problem with texturing cone. I tried to do UV with Mark Seam the texture imposed vad. I tried Cylinder and Sphere projection, bad too. I need to improse tile to cone. How I can recive this problem? Thanks!  [image]

Comment: I think one method or the other could be better depending on which texture you're using, where are details etc. If you can give at least an example of it, or of the desired result... that would get you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you, I add one pic more for better explain. See please. Its tile in SP. U can see bugs in 3d view.